# Show the total sale in Hourly basis

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to generate a report sales report for current day in which user will select start hour and end hour.
It will be max 24 hours.
Start hour will be 4:00 AM and max end hour can be next day 4:00 AM

**The below query will return date-time and amount of sale**

```
select s.StartDate ,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(OrigionalSubTotal)/100.0) Amt from Sale s
    where 
    s.StartDate
    BETWEEN '2015-07-03 04:00:01'
     and '2015-07-04 04:00:00' 
     and s.IsSuspend = 0  and s.IsTrainMode = 0 and wasrefunded=0
    and IsCancelled = 0
    group by S.StartDate
    order by s.StartDate
```

**O/p**

```
   StartDate                Amt
2015-07-03 17:01:15.780    10.00
2015-07-03 18:45:57.360    10.00
2015-07-03 18:48:41.250    20.00
2015-07-03 19:02:50.850    5.00
2015-07-03 19:04:45.090    15.00
2015-07-03 19:18:38.960    10.00
2015-07-03 21:12:25.700    100.00
2015-07-03 21:16:30.730    20.00
2015-07-03 22:21:09.380    30.00
2015-07-03 23:38:32.050    34.00
2015-07-04 00:39:46.790    200.00
2015-07-04 01:00:14.820    106.00
```

From this I need to take hourly sales
Consider current day is `03-July-2015`
Let say user select `16:00 (04:00 PM) - 04:00 AM (next day 04-July-2015)`.

**Then the desired o/p should be like below**

```
  Hour                Amount
 16:00 - 17:00            0.00     -- No sale row between this time
 17:00 - 18:00           10.00     -- sale between 17:00 to 17:59
 18:00 - 19:00           30.00
 19:00 - 20:00           30.00
 20:00 - 21:00            0.00     -- No sale row between this time
 21:00 - 22:00          120.00
 22:00 - 23:00           30.00
 23:00 - 0:00            34:00
 0:00  - 1:00            200.00
 1:00  - 2:00            106.00
 2:00  - 3:00            0.00
 3:00  - 4:00            0.00
```

**I tried below query to achieve this**

```
select STUFF(CONVERT(CHAR(13), s.StartDate , 120), 11, 1, ' ') ,
       DATEPART(HOUR,s.startdate),
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(OrigionalSubTotal)/100.0) from Sale s
where 
s.StartDate
BETWEEN '2015-07-03 04:00:01'
 and '2015-07-04 04:00:00' 
 and s.IsSuspend = 0  and s.IsTrainMode = 0 and wasrefunded=0
and IsCancelled = 0
group by STUFF(CONVERT(CHAR(13), s.StartDate , 120), 11, 1, ' '),DATEPART(HOUR,s.startdate)
order by STUFF(CONVERT(CHAR(13), s.StartDate , 120), 11, 1, ' '),DATEPART(HOUR,s.startdate)
```

**O/P is like below**

```
Date           Hour  Amt
2015-07-03 17   17  10.00
2015-07-03 18   18  30.00
2015-07-03 19   19  30.00
2015-07-03 21   21  120.00
2015-07-03 22   22  30.00
2015-07-04 23   23  34.00
2015-07-04 0    0   200.00
2015-07-04 01   1   106.00
```

How can I achieve the desired o/p from this. Please help.

**Edited**
**Table structure**

```
Saleid  - Unqiueidentifier  eg:- 5D0AC452-2F01-E511-8502-0019178A0F32

startDate - datetime     eg:- 2015-05-23 13:37:32.880

OrigionalSubTotal - int  eg: 5400  (last two digit is decimal)its table of customized software i cannot change the type
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99562/2)

Comment: If `StartDate` isn't already from type datetime, you should cast it to datetime.
Then you don't need Char-`CONVERT` and the `Stuff` functions.
The rest of your approach is ok i think.
If you post more code for the create of the table (so one can see the types) and some inserts, I can create a query which will create the desired result.

Comment: @Ulli edited my question with table structure.

Comment: It would be great if you can create sqlfilddle

Comment: @DarkKnight fiddle created link at question

Comment: @Darkknight one more issue..if I am giving a time interval it is not 24 hours gap it is showing each row as duplicate. also it show all time interval..which is not in the range i given..see this fiddle [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/706a3/2) i tried to solve it..by distinct i am able to restrict the repetition but time interval i am not able to solve

Comment: @Darkknight now it work if the date is same if date is one day ahead no result..eg:- `2015-07-03 16:00:00 - 2015-07-03 19:00:00` give exact result but `2015-07-03 16:00:00 - 2015-07-04 03:00:00` return no rows. –

Comment: @Darkknight sorry for disturbing you frequently\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 declare @starttime datetime = '2015-07-03 16:00:01'
 declare @endtime datetime =   '2015-07-04 04:00:00' 

;with reporttable as 
(
   select s.StartDate ,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(OrigionalSubTotal)/100.0) Amt from Sale s
    where 
    s.StartDate
    BETWEEN @starttime
     and @endtime
     and s.IsSuspend = 0  and s.IsTrainMode = 0 and wasrefunded=0
    and IsCancelled = 0
    group by S.StartDate
),
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 0 AS HR
    UNION ALL
    SELECT HR+1 AS HR FROM CTE WHERE HR<23
)
,cte1 as
(
SELECT (select cast(min(startdate) as date) from ReportTable) as [date],c.hr as hr,cast(c.hr as varchar(100))+'-'+cast(c.hr+1 as varchar(100)) as period,sum(isnull(originalsubtotal,0)) as total
FROM CTE c
        left join ReportTable RT on c.hr = datepart(hh,rt.startDate) and cast(rt.startdate as date) = (select cast(min(startdate) as date) from ReportTable)
group by c.hr,cast(rt.startdate as date)

union all

SELECT (select cast(max(startdate) as date) from ReportTable) as  [date],c.hr as hr,cast(c.hr as varchar(100))+'-'+cast(c.hr+1 as varchar(100)) as period,sum(isnull(originalsubtotal,0)) as total
FROM CTE c
        left join ReportTable RT on c.hr = datepart(hh,rt.startDate) and cast(rt.startdate as date) = (select cast(max(startdate) as date) from ReportTable)
group by c.hr,cast(rt.startdate as date)
)
select * from cte1 where (cast([date] as date)=cast(@starttime as date) and hr>=datepart(hh,@starttime)) and (cast([date] as date)=cast(@endtime as date) and hr<=datepart(hh,@endtime))
order by [date],hr
```

Comment: perfect..will test it for some more days :) Thanks for the quick response

Comment: i removed my edited part from your answer..it seems fine..will test for some more data and will mark it as answer..thanks

Comment: @Sachu : can you please create sqlfiddle with the updated query which gives you the error? having hard time in relating error with your code.

Comment: thanks for the quick response..my code working now :) thanks a lot if any pblm next time i will create a fiddle and post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89397/discussion-between-sachu-and-dark-knight).

Comment: one more issue..if I am giving a time interval it is not 24 hours gap it is showing each row as duplicate. also it show all time interval..which is not in the range i given..see this fiddle [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/706a3/2) i tried to solve it..by distinct i am able to restrict the repetition but time interval i am not able to solve

Comment: now it work if the date is same if date is one day ahead no result..eg:- `2015-07-03 16:00:00 - 2015-07-03 19:00:00` give exact result but `2015-07-03 16:00:00 -  2015-07-04 03:00:00` return no rows.

Comment: @Sachu : try replacing `where` condition with this `dateadd(hour,hr,cast([date] as datetime)) between @starttime and @endtime` and let me know how it goes.

Comment: one issue
if we give 2015-07-03 04:00:00 - 2015-07-03 22:00:00 as input
the o/p should end by 21-22
but it go one more row with 22-23
if 2015-07-03 04:00:00 - 2015-07-04 01:00:00 then last row will be 01-02
1 row coming more..other than that its fine

Comment: Can you try with this `dateadd(hour,hr,cast([date] as datetime))>=@starttime and dateadd(hour,hr,cast([date] as datetime))<@endtime`. Just play around with this condition.

Answer (score 1):

I've approached this in two steps:

1. Get the range of `datetime` values using `MIN` and `MAX` on the data
2. Use these values to create the full range of dates and hours in a [**CTE**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and join them back on to the data.

The CTE will produce this lookup table to join back on to the main data:

```
|    DateVal | HourVal |
|------------|---------|
| 2015-07-03 |      17 |
| 2015-07-03 |      18 |
| 2015-07-03 |      19 |
| 2015-07-03 |      20 |
| 2015-07-03 |      21 |
| 2015-07-03 |      22 |
| 2015-07-03 |      23 |
| 2015-07-04 |       0 |
| 2015-07-04 |       1 |
```

**Runnable sample:**

The sample code is commented to explain what each step is doing.

```
-- dummy table
CREATE TABLE #Sale
    (
      [StartDate] DATETIME ,
      [Amt] INT
    );

-- fill dummy data
INSERT  INTO #Sale
        ( [StartDate], [Amt] )
VALUES  ( '2015-07-03 17:01:15', 10.00 ),
        ( '2015-07-03 18:45:57', 10.00 ),
        ( '2015-07-03 18:48:41', 20.00 ),
        ( '2015-07-03 19:02:50', 5.00 ),
        ( '2015-07-03 19:04:45', 15.00 ),
        ( '2015-07-03 19:18:38', 10.00 ),
        ( '2015-07-03 21:12:25', 100.00 ),
        ( '2015-07-03 21:16:30', 20.00 ),
        ( '2015-07-03 22:21:09', 30.00 ),
        ( '2015-07-03 23:38:32', 34.00 ),
        ( '2015-07-04 00:39:46', 200.00 ),
        ( '2015-07-04 01:00:14', 106.00 );

DECLARE @minDate DATETIME ,
    @maxDate DATETIME

-- set min date
SELECT TOP 1
        @minDate = StartDate
FROM    #Sale
ORDER BY StartDate

-- set max date
SELECT TOP 1
        @maxDate = StartDate
FROM    #Sale
ORDER BY StartDate DESC

-- cte to iterate between min and max, to generate unique date and hour vals for range
;WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   CONVERT(DATE, StartDate) AS DateVal ,
                        DATEPART(HOUR, StartDate) AS HourVal
               FROM     #Sale
               WHERE    StartDate = @minDate
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   CASE WHEN cte.HourVal + 1 > 23
                             THEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, cte.DateVal)
                             ELSE cte.DateVal
                        END AS DateVal ,
                        CASE WHEN cte.HourVal + 1 = 24 THEN 0
                             ELSE cte.HourVal + 1
                        END AS HourVal
               FROM     cte
               WHERE    DATEADD(HOUR, CASE WHEN cte.HourVal + 1 = 24 THEN 0
                                           ELSE cte.HourVal + 1
                                      END,
                                CONVERT(DATETIME, CASE WHEN cte.HourVal + 1 = 24
                                                       THEN DATEADD(DAY, 1,
                                                              cte.DateVal)
                                                       ELSE cte.DateVal
                                                  END)) <= @maxDate
             )
-- join results of cte to source data on date and hour with sum/group by
    SELECT  cte.DateVal ,
            cte.HourVal ,
            -- covers hours with no sales
            COALESCE(SUM(s.Amt), 0) AS Amt
    FROM    cte
            LEFT JOIN #Sale s ON cte.DateVal = CONVERT(DATE, s.StartDate)
                                 AND cte.HourVal = DATEPART(HOUR, s.StartDate)
    GROUP BY cte.DateVal ,
            cte.HourVal
    ORDER BY cte.DateVal ,
            cte.HourVal

DROP TABLE #Sale
```

**Output**

```
|    DateVal | HourVal | Amt |
|------------|---------|-----|
| 2015-07-03 |      17 |  10 |
| 2015-07-03 |      18 |  30 |
| 2015-07-03 |      19 |  30 |
| 2015-07-03 |      20 |   0 |
| 2015-07-03 |      21 | 120 |
| 2015-07-03 |      22 |  30 |
| 2015-07-03 |      23 |  34 |
| 2015-07-04 |       0 | 200 |
| 2015-07-04 |       1 | 106 |
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1da04/1)

I've ignored the outliers in the above, as there is no data outside the range of the min/max dates. If you need this, you can of course tweak the min/max values as shown in the code below. This modified version will take user input for the date range to produce your desired output:

```
DECLARE @minDate DATETIME ,
    @maxDate DATETIME

-- set min date
SET @minDate = '2015-07-03 16:00:00'

-- set max date
SET @maxDate = '2015-07-04 04:00:00'

-- cte to iterate between min and max, to generate unique date and hour vals for range
;WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   CONVERT(DATE, @minDate) AS DateVal ,
                        DATEPART(HOUR, @minDate) AS HourVal
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   CASE WHEN cte.HourVal + 1 > 23
                             THEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, cte.DateVal)
                             ELSE cte.DateVal
                        END AS DateVal ,
                        CASE WHEN cte.HourVal + 1 = 24 THEN 0
                             ELSE cte.HourVal + 1
                        END AS HourVal
               FROM     cte
               WHERE    DATEADD(HOUR, CASE WHEN cte.HourVal + 1 = 24 THEN 0
                                           ELSE cte.HourVal + 1
                                      END,
                                CONVERT(DATETIME, CASE WHEN cte.HourVal + 1 = 24
                                                       THEN DATEADD(DAY, 1,
                                                              cte.DateVal)
                                                       ELSE cte.DateVal
                                                  END)) <= @maxDate
             )
-- join results of cte to source data on date and hour with sum/group by
SELECT  cte.DateVal ,
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2),cte.HourVal) + ':00 -' +  
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2),cte.HourVal+1) + ':00' AS [Hours],
        -- covers hours with no sales
        COALESCE(SUM(s.Amt), 0) AS Amt
FROM    cte
        LEFT JOIN #Sale s ON cte.DateVal = CONVERT(DATE, s.StartDate)
                             AND cte.HourVal = DATEPART(HOUR, s.StartDate)
GROUP BY cte.DateVal ,
        cte.HourVal
ORDER BY cte.DateVal ,
        cte.HourVal
```

**Ouput**

```
|    DateVal |        Hours | Amt |
|------------|--------------|-----|
| 2015-07-03 | 16:00 -17:00 |   0 |
| 2015-07-03 | 17:00 -18:00 |  10 |
| 2015-07-03 | 18:00 -19:00 |  30 |
| 2015-07-03 | 19:00 -20:00 |  30 |
| 2015-07-03 | 20:00 -21:00 |   0 |
| 2015-07-03 | 21:00 -22:00 | 120 |
| 2015-07-03 | 22:00 -23:00 |  30 |
| 2015-07-03 | 23:00 -24:00 |  34 |
| 2015-07-04 |   0:00 -1:00 | 200 |
| 2015-07-04 |   1:00 -2:00 | 106 |
| 2015-07-04 |   2:00 -3:00 |   0 |
| 2015-07-04 |   3:00 -4:00 |   0 |
| 2015-07-04 |   4:00 -5:00 |   0 |
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1da04/4)

Comment: thanks for the effort but this is the output which i got..my desired out put is not this.

Comment: the output is correct, you just have to make 17 -> 17.00-18.00... can you manage that? also if you want the outer hours with no data, add/subtract hours from min/max values like i stated in post.

Comment: I understood the output should always have all 12 Hours from 16 to 4.

Comment: @Sachu see edit, I've added what's required to produce the desired output

Comment: @Tanner nice..only change is i need to pass the input of user to the procedure and assign to `@mindate` and `@maxdate`

Comment: @Tanner i edited your answer with the o/p from my system..there is a small issue..can you help me

Comment: @Sachu I've edited my answer back, as your content doesn't make up an answer, it is critique. If you want to add more information then you should either add it to your question or add it as comments on the answers. Besides that, I can't answer without seeing the data that you are using to verify the accuracy.

Comment: @Sachu if the code isn't working, i suggest you edit my fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1da04/4 with some data that doesn't produce the output you require.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a temp table with the 12 Hours in it and then join that against your aggregated data:

```
-- declare temporary output table
DECLARE @output table (pos int, HourInt int, [Hour] varchar(20))

-- define some variables
DECLARE @counter int = 0
DECLARE @maxCount int = 12
DECLARE @beginHour int = 16
DECLARE @currentHour int = 0
DECLARE @followHour int = 0

-- loop from 16 o'clock to 4 o'clock 
WHILE @counter < @maxCount
BEGIN
    SET @currentHour = @beginHour + @counter
    IF @currentHour > 23 BEGIN SET @currentHour = @currentHour - 24 END 
    SET @followHour = @currentHour + 1   
    IF @followHour > 23 BEGIN SET @followHour = @followHour - 24 END 

    -- create one row in temp table for this hour
    INSERT INTO @output SELECT @counter, @currentHour, CAST(@currentHour AS varchar) + ':00 - ' + CAST(@followHour AS varchar) + ':00'

    SET @counter = @counter + 1

END

-- Left Join temp table with sale table, rows with no data shows zero
SELECT o.[Hour], ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),SUM(s.OrigionalSubTotal)/100.0),0) AS Amt
FROM @output o LEFT JOIN Sale s ON o.HourInt = DATEPART(HOUR,s.startdate)
WHERE (s.StartDate  
    BETWEEN '2015-07-03 04:00:01'
    AND '2015-07-04 04:00:00')
    OR s.StartDate IS NULL
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR,s.startdate), o.[Hour], o.pos
ORDER BY o.pos
```

**Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99562/7) for it**

Comment: the ouput won't always from 16 to 4. It depends on user input. I hope your answer is fine. Only change i have to do is assign the `starting hour` given by user to `@beginHour` and difference between `start` and `end` to @maxcount

Comment: this also works..thanks for the great effort..will upvote

Answer (score 0):

```
Select cast('2015-07-03 17:01:15.780' as datetime) as StartDate ,    10.00 as Amt
into #temp
union all
Select '2015-07-03 18:45:57.360',    10.00
union all
Select '2015-07-03 18:48:41.250',    20.00
union all
Select '2015-07-03 19:02:50.850',    5.00
union all
Select '2015-07-03 19:04:45.090',    15.00
union all
Select '2015-07-03 19:18:38.960',    10.00
union all
Select '2015-07-03 21:12:25.700',    100.00
union all
Select '2015-07-03 21:16:30.730',    20.00
union all
Select '2015-07-03 22:21:09.380',    30.00
union all
Select '2015-07-03 23:38:32.050',    34.00
union all
Select '2015-07-04 00:39:46.790',    200.00
union all
Select '2015-07-04 01:00:14.820',    106.00

declare @cntr int, @maxCounter int
set @cntr = 0
set @maxCounter = (SELECT datediff(hh,DATEADD(hh,DATEDIFF(hh,0,min(startdate)),0),DATEADD(hh,DATEDIFF(hh,0,Max(startdate))+1,0))  from #temp)

Create table #hrsrange
(
DateID int,
StartDate datetime,
EndDate datetime
)

WHILE (@cntr <= @maxCounter)
BEGIN
Insert into #hrsrange
SELECT distinct @cntr+1 as DateID,
DateAdd(hh,@cntr,(SELECT DATEADD(hh,DATEDIFF(hh,0,min(startdate)),0)  from #temp)) as StartDate, 
DateAdd(hh,@cntr+1,(SELECT DATEADD(hh,DATEDIFF(hh,0,min(startdate)),0)  from #temp)) as EndDate
from #temp
SET @cntr = @cntr + 1
End

select  cast(DATEPART(hh,hr.StartDate) as varchar)+' - '+ cast(DATEPART(hh,hr.EndDate) as varchar)
,sum(s.Amt)/100.0 as Amt 
from #temp s
left join #hrsrange hr
on cast(s.StartDate as datetime) between hr.StartDate and hr.EndDate 
  group by DATEPART(hh,hr.StartDate),DATEPART(hh,hr.EndDate)
```